# Injecting all beans of the same type with CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, interface, cdi, managed-bean, multiple-instances

Suppose we have a package `foos` containing classes, which all of them implements some `IFoo`.

We also have a class, `Baz` which contains a data-member, `List<IFoo> fooList`.
Is it possible to inject dynamically all those `IFoo` classes into `fooList`?

By the way, is it a common practice? (I'm new with the DI concept)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance` interface to dynamically obtain all instances of `Foo`:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Baz {

    @Inject
    Instance<Foo> foos;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        for (Foo foo : foos) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This totally makes sense, e.g. if you want to merge the results of multiple service provider implementations. You find a good study example [here](https://github.com/pdudits/x-ray/blob/master/x-ray-services/src/main/java/com/abien/xray/business/configuration/boundary/Configuration.java).

See also:

- [JSR-000346 Contexts and Dependency Injection for JavaTM EE 1.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr346/index.html),
  *Section 5.6. Programmatic lookup*

Comment: Thank you. Haven't tried it yet but it looks promising :)

Comment: does this work also with @Stateless Foo implementations?

Comment: @Frank I could not find any specific statement about EJBs in the specs for this case, but I can confirm that this works on WildFly and I assume that instance lookup is intended to be compatible between CDI and EJB world.

Comment: @Jens If the type of the Instance is an interface it seems to work with non-stateless beans only.

Comment: @Frank Does your beans.xml contain `bean-discovery-mode="all"`?

Comment: @Jens Yes, it does implicitly because my beans.xml is empty.